# Asp.Net Custom Resource Provider : non-updatable build

Tags: asp.net, resource-file

In my asp.net web site i'm using customized resource provider to fetch local resource information from database,

```
<globalization resourceProviderFactoryType="MyCustomResourceProvider" culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US">
```

It is working fine while i debug from visual studio or publish using "precompile site to be updatable" mode set to true. But when i change the "updatable" mode to false, it is not hitting my custom resource provider for any page.

Anyone have faced this problem before ?

Update 1:
When i explored the generated assembly,  i found that code for fetching local resources has not been generated, somehow aspnet_compiler  is not adding the required code if i use custom resource provider.